# Twice JSON Request instead of one

Tags: json, swift

My JSON request works fine but every time I do a request the network monitor shows me there are two requests made. What is wrong here? How can I optimize it to just one?
I tried to find the reason for this and it looks like it has to happen here with this request.

```
struct networkGoogleApi {
    
    static var testVariable = [Items]()
    static var gewählteKategorie = 0

    mutating func fetchPoi(geoCordinate: String) {
        
        var baseUrlToApiConnection = ""
        baseUrlToApiConnection = {
            switch networkGoogleApi.gewählteKategorie {
            case 0:
                return
               "first url"
            case 1:
                return "other url"
            default:
                return "error"
            }
        }()
        
        let urlString = "\(baseUrlToApiConnection)?at=\(geoCordinate)"
        print(urlString)
        performRequest(urlString: urlString)
    }
    
    func performRequest(urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    parseJSON(poiData: safeData)
                    
                }
            }
            //4. Start the task
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}


func parseJSON(poiData: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(POIData.self, from: poiData)
        networkGoogleApi.testVariable = decodedData.items
        //print(networkGoogleApi.testVariable)
        
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
}
```

Breakpoint Event added.
[image]

Comment: Create a breakpoint in the beginning of the `performRequest` method and check how many times it gets called. Likely it's called two times in a row in quick succession. Use the stack trace in the Xcode's debug navigator to figure out why it's called twice.

Comment: It is the first time I use breakpoints. Am I doing it correctly? Is this the reason for calling twice? I see networkGoogleApi.performRequest(urlString: ) and networkGoogleApi.fetchPoi(geoCordinate:). Or did you mean before Line 38?

Comment: That's the stack trace, i.e. a sequence of methods calling one another. Here we see that the whole call hierarchy started from `ViewController.mapView(_:didChange)`. If you continue the execution, the debugger will likely stop again on the same line and probably with the same call stack. So every time your map gets updated, a new network request fires away. I highly recommend that you get yourself familiar with the Xcode debugger, it will be a huge help is solving problems like that. Start from the Debugging section here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode